# What is the level number of an element present in an array of n integers interpreted as a complete binary tree?

Tags: binary-tree, binary-search-tree

If I am given an array X of n distinct integers which is interpreted as a complete binary tree so if the parent is at index i , then it's left child would be at index 2i and it's right child would be at index 2i+1 , so Now if root is considered to be at level 0 , then how can we find the level of an element X[i] ?

I followed the approach of first considering the fact that at a level k , I would be having 2^k nodes, so I just considered that in the array starting from certain index a upto b , I have all the numbers at the same level k , so in a particular portion I have 2^k nodes inclusive of a and b , so before a , total no of nodes , are 
2^0+2^1+2^2+.....+2^k-1 ,since index a is at level k , so before it there would be k-1 levels ,so I summed them all up , Now I am stucked up while calculating the value of b , so please guide about how to calculate the value of b ?

Answer (score 0):

If a is 2<sup>k</sup>, then b is 2<sup>k+1</sup>-1.

Comment: Can you please explain your logic since b would be at level 2^k only so then how come did you get 2^k+1 ?

Comment: To *prove* this rule, use induction: if the k-level nodes are [2^k,...,2^(k+1)-1], then their children (the (k+1)-level nodes) will be [2^(k+1),...,2^(k+2)-1]. To *discover* this rule, just play around with the low levels: the root is level 0, and we'll assume it's at index 1 (because if it were at [0], its own left child would also be at [0]), so k=0:{[1]}, k=1:{[2],[3]}, k=2:{[4],[5],[6],[7]}, k=3:{[8],[9],[10],[11],[12],[13],[14],[15]} and the pattern jumps out at you.